# Why is this invalid json -validators shows error but looks ok to me?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I constructed a json string.
When I test it on  https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator it says it's not valid. I don't see what's wrong with it.

```
[{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0040","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 501","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"08/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Unable to process sale due to deed errors"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0080","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 901","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$485,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0190","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 302","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"04/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0190","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 302","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"01/2019","Amount":"$420,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0310","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1602","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0390","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 303","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"07/2019","Amount":"$459,000","Qualification Description":"Financial inst or In Lieu of Forclosure stated"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0530","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1803","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"07/2019","Amount":"$0","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0830","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1405","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"06/2019","Amount":"$500,000","Qualification Description":"Trustees in bankruptcy, executors or guardians"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0870","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1805","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"07/2019","Amount":"$1,305,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0950","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1106","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"04/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1030","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2006","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$560,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1080","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2506","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1130","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 507","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"01/2019","Amount":"$430,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1210","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1407","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$550,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1310","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2407","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"08/2019","Amount":"$550,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1580","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2408","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"10/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2080","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2010","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"10/2019","Amount":"$550,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2090","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2110","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"06/2019","Amount":"$506,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2270","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1511","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"05/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2310","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1911","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living 
Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2510","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 412","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2520","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 512","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"04/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3060","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 3500","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"5,200 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"5,200 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"02/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3160","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 614","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"06/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3240","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1514","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Life Estate interest"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3410","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 715","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 
101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"800 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"800 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"08/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3500","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1715","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"01/2019","Amount":"$465,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3590","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2615","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"11/2019","Amount":"$562,500","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"}]
```

Comment: you need this site https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Hi, I saw on your profile that all your questions have unaccepted answers. If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer y clicking the check mark. See: [How do I accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/762149). But only if your question really has been answered. You can also go back on your previous questions to accept the answers that resolved them.

Answer (score 2):

Because at the end of line 1 your string cuts off.

Where it should say `"Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft"`, you instead have `"Living`, a new line, and `Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft"`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 new lines in your json.

This one is your json fixed:

```
[{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0040","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 501","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"08/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Unable to process sale due to deed errors"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0080","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 901","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$485,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0190","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 302","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"04/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0190","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 302","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"01/2019","Amount":"$420,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0310","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1602","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0390","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 303","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"07/2019","Amount":"$459,000","Qualification Description":"Financial inst or In Lieu of Forclosure stated"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0530","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1803","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"07/2019","Amount":"$0","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0830","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1405","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"06/2019","Amount":"$500,000","Qualification Description":"Trustees in bankruptcy, executors or guardians"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0870","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1805","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"07/2019","Amount":"$1,305,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0950","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1106","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"04/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1030","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2006","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$560,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1080","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2506","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1130","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 507","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"01/2019","Amount":"$430,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1210","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1407","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$550,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1310","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2407","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"08/2019","Amount":"$550,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1580","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2408","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"10/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2080","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2010","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"10/2019","Amount":"$550,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2090","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2110","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"06/2019","Amount":"$506,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2270","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1511","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"05/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2310","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1911","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2510","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 412","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2520","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 512","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"04/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3060","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 3500","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"5,200 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"5,200 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"02/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3160","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 614","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"06/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3240","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1514","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Life Estate interest"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3410","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 715","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"800 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"800 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"08/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3500","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1715","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"01/2019","Amount":"$465,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3590","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2615","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"11/2019","Amount":"$562,500","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

After validating it on [this site](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) seems like you have some syntax errors. Have a look at these

[image]
[image]

Here I fixed the json:

```js
   [{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0040","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 501","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"08/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Unable to process sale due to deed errors"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0080","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 901","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$485,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0190","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 302","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"04/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0190","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 302","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"01/2019","Amount":"$420,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0310","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1602","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0390","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 303","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"07/2019","Amount":"$459,000","Qualification Description":"Financial inst or In Lieu of Forclosure stated"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0530","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1803","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"07/2019","Amount":"$0","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0830","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1405","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"06/2019","Amount":"$500,000","Qualification Description":"Trustees in bankruptcy, executors or guardians"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0870","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1805","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"07/2019","Amount":"$1,305,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-0950","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1106","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"04/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1030","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2006","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$560,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1080","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2506","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1130","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 507","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"01/2019","Amount":"$430,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1210","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1407","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$550,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1310","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2407","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"08/2019","Amount":"$550,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-1580","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2408","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"2,130 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"10/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2080","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2010","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"10/2019","Amount":"$550,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2090","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2110","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"06/2019","Amount":"$506,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2270","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1511","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"05/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2310","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1911","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"12/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2510","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 412","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-2520","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 512","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"04/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3060","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 3500","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"5,200 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"5,200 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"02/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3160","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 614","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"06/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3240","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1514","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,610 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"03/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Life Estate interest"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3410","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 715","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"800 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"800 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"08/2019","Amount":"$100","Qualification Description":"Corrective, tax or QCD; min consideration"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3500","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 1715","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,660 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"01/2019","Amount":"$465,000","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"},{"#":"28*","Folio":"28-2203-057-3590","Address":"3370 HIDDEN BAY DR 2615","Property Use":"CONDO - RESIDENTIAL","PA Zoning":"MULTI-FAMILY - 101+ U/A","Year Built":"2000","Actual Area":"Sq.Ft","Living Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Adj Area":"1,870 Sq.Ft","Lot Size":"0 Sq.Ft","#Beds":"0","#Baths":"0","Sale Month":"11/2019","Amount":"$562,500","Qualification Description":"Qual by exam of deed"}]
```

Also have a look at this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem was that I needed to paste plain text into the validator. When I did that the json was valid.